# Access field - default value + limit numbers

Tags: ms-access

I have one numeric field from table, where I need to put a default value "100", and after that there should be allowed 5 more numbers.

Currently I have :

- Default value: 100
- Input mask: 00000000;; " "

But what this does is that It puts default value into field, but not on field's first left place, although I have set Text align of field to left. How can I set this to have default value in left beginning of field - and allow 5 numbers after that ?

P.S.: Input mask "100"00000;; " " doesn't solve issues, because 100 is not being saved in table in this case.

EDIT:

When I use input mask "100"00000;;" ", I can't search these records via VBA Dynamic SQL search, because "100" is not being saved in table. Even If you add same input mask to Table and see the full number, Dynamic SQL doesn't work - because Access doesn't save Input mask as field data.

Comment: What does this field represent? I think if you change it to a text field the input mask will work properly, but whether or not you should depends on what you're storing in it.

Comment: This field represents field of a table. I'm using It to save records directly to table. I know about Text field, I have set another unbound Textbox with same settings, and Default value gets in beginning of field, problem is only with this bound Textbox.

Comment: If it's bound then you need to change the data type in the table, not the format of the text box. It won't work the same way as your unbound text box. Whether it's the right thing to do depends on what the field represents. For example, zip codes, phone numbers, SS# are made up of numbers but should be stored as text data types in the tables.

Comment: Ok, then I'm in a trouble. It's number field, and It has to be number field, because I'm using this data type to Import data into table too.

Comment: Seems to me, you request '100' & 5 more **Digits**, not numbers. Am I correct?

Comment: I don't see difference between digits and numbers, but yes that is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

*Assumptions*:

1) this field is a long integer with a field size of 8, and it cannot be changed to a text field

2) this was tested in Access 2016 on Windows 8.1 Pro

-

Set the Input Mask of the field's **table** properties to:
    "100"#####;;" "

Set the default value of the field's **table** properties to `NULL`. Do so by highlighting the default value and pressing backspace and then enter. The property should now be totally blank.

Set the text align of the **table** properties to `Left`

Now the table shows no value until selected, at which point it will have "100" properly left-justified with 5 spaces as placeholders.

On the **form**, set the textbox input mask property to:
    "100"#####;;" " and your text align: `Left`.

Make the **form** default value `NULL` in the same way.

Again, now the **form** textbox with show your default value when selected, but otherwise appears blank.

That's the best I can do. Since it's a number field, any default value in the table (other than `NULL`) will appear right-justified regardless of your input mask. If your default value infringes upon the literal characters in your input mask, the field appears with the default value only. For example:

Input Mask: "100"#####;;" "

Deafult Value: 999999

Appeared as: 999999

-

If you must have "100" appear in the field on your form, the only option I can see would be to add a **label** behind your **textbox** with the same size and same text properties.

Make your **label** caption "100" (and text align to `Left`).

Then set the **textbox** background color property to `Transparent`.

That will let you see the default value stored in the label through the textbox. When the textbox is selected, the label is blocked by the white background color of the input of the textbox, which shows the correct value. Assuming your fonts don't clash, the textbox value should appear cleanly enough, since "100" will always be the first three characters.

Comment: Cristopher, thanks for your post, but that won't do. I haven't elaborate this - from a form I save records directly to table. These numbers are serial no. of certain items....PROBLEM: I have a VBA Dynamic SQL search, and when I perform search for these records, they are not found. I investigated and my conclusion is that because "100" is not stored as value in table, but just like input mask, so record is not found - If I search record without "100", record is found. It sounds strange, but that's how Access behaves. I can also post VBA code for Dynamic search If needed.

Comment: @LuckyLuke82  Please edit your original question with this info. -1 for not phrasing your question properly. Good luck!

Comment: I know you said the import process prevents converting this to a text data type, but adding cstr() around the import value is much easier than working around bad design. There may be a solution to this, but these constraints aren't super realistic. Not to say this should never happen, but fixing the table design is the best overall fix in most situations.

Comment: Ok, It think I understand you, but... can you post an example of this, for future references ?

Comment: @LuckyLuke82 I'm assuming you're asking about `CStr()`. `CStr()` is a Convert function that takes a value of any data type, like Long Integer, and converts it into text so it can be stored in a text field. If you need to edit your import procedure, open a separate question to answer that.

Comment: I know what CStr is, I just never seen how can you use It with Import, nothing else. Nevermind, If you don't have time you don't need to post anything, I won't change my Imports.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109712/discussion-between-christopher-d-and-luckyluke82).